# Using boost::format in a boost::lambda

Tags: c++, boost-lambda, boost-format

For some reason, I fail to use `boost::format` in a `boost::lambda`. Here is a (hopefully) compilable simplification of my code :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

namespace bl = boost::lambda;

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3);
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bl::var(std::cout) << std::setw(10) << bl::_1);
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bl::var(std::cout) << boost::format("%10d") % bl::_1);
}
```

- The first `std::for_each` produces the expected output
- The second `std::for_each` only outputs whitespaces without any number

Why is that ? I'm really not familiar with `boost::lambda` so I might be missing the obvious here.

Please do not suggest `std::copy` based answers : my actual code does not work on `std::vector` but on `boost::fusion::vector` (and `std::for_each` is in fact a `boost::fusion::for_each`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, your code evaluates `boost::format("%10d") % bl::_1` immediately, rather than on each invocation of the lambda.

To prevent this, you need to wrap `boost::format("%10d")` in a call to `bl::var`, just as you have done with `std::cout`.

Unfortunately, doing this requires Boost.Lambda to deduce the return type of the call to `operator%`, which it is unable to do. Therefore the return type must be specified explicitly, using `bl::ret`. Note that this return type must be a reference, in order that `std::cout` accesses the returned object directly rather than a copy of it.

We thus get the following code, which produces the expected output:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bl::var(std::cout) <<
    bl::ret<const boost::format &>(bl::var(boost::format("%10d")) % bl::_1));
```

Comment: yep, this works, but I have no idea why it is necessary ! `boost::lambda::var` should only be necessary when neither arguments is a lambda expression. I was aiming for a nice and concise syntax using `boost::lambda` :( Too bad

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that you're running into the fact that a format used is no longer usable.

```
boost::format f("...");

std::string s = f % ... ;
std::string s2 = f % other options...; // FAIL!  f has been changed by the above use!
```

In other words, using % on a format actually replaces the string data with whatever you %'d into it.  The cooler thing is that the second use above will *silently* fail.

I know, kind of counter-intuitive, but it is what it is.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I believe the code you provided works as expected. To quote boost.format documentation "Once all arguments have been fed you can dump the format object to a stream. [...] The result string stays accessible in the format object until another argument is passed, at which time it is reinitialised." The second `%` does indeed reinitialize the format, but that should be a good thing in my case !

Comment: In my experience it doesn't but if your millage varies I suggest ignoring my response.  No idea what else your problem could be.